# Powershell - Get part of a file path up to a point from a CSV

Tags: powershell

Need some help with a substring please? I have a csv which contains file paths in column A.

These paths have .foo at the end (appended from the original query).

Is there a way to use a substring (or something else) which will search the path\text and return the content up until this point for example

C:\test folder\Folder1\Test 2\filename.abc(foo)
and return
C:\test folder\Folder1\Test 2\filename.abc

I dont really have any sample code as Im just starting out - thanks.

Comment: Ready this please https://stackoverflow.com/tour. Also in your example does the first part always have some similar combinations like .tst or even as you wrote (foo) ?

Comment: Hi - yes the combinations will always end with (foo). Really appreciate your help thanks :)

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to write this for you but I will give you an example and some things to read to get you going. Make sure to take the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Jump in to your code by writing some code and then come ask again. These articles here will help you with what you want.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/trim-your-strings-with-powershell/

or

https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-split-path/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7.2

Here is an example I made for you

```
$file = (Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\dnd.txt | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name).Split('.')[0]
```

There are a ton of ways to do what you are asking and my example is not even a start. Write some code, define your goals and come ask again.

a different example

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/two-simple-powershell-methods-to-remove-the-last-letter-of-a-string/

```
$file = Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\dnd.txt | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
$file = $file.Substring(0,$file.Length - 3)
$file
```

Corrected again. Please understand there are better ways to do what I did and you really need to explain what you want better.

---

Last one :)

Let's assume you have a file called example.csv in the c:\temp folder.

Inside the file example.csv are a bunch of paths with something you need to strip of the end and then output the results.

Contents of example.csv

```
head
c:\temp\fileafoo
c:\temp\filebfoo
c:\temp\filestuffcfoo
```

The code

```
$paths = $null
$paths = Import-Csv C:\temp\example.csv | ForEach-Object{

    $var = $null
    $var = $_.head

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Corrected = $var.substring(0,$var.length - 3)
    }
}

$paths
```

Results are

```
Corrected
---------    
c:\temp\filea
c:\temp\fileb
c:\temp\filestuffc
```

And you can export this with `$paths | Export-csv c:\temp\result.csv  -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: Thanks dcaz - if I use split (hope you dont mind me asking questions) wont that just split the output to effectively .abc and (foo) respectively? When Im only after the first part?

Comment: That is what the ```[0]``` is for. Try what I did with your own test. Don't forget to accept the answer. Generally your question should lay out what you are trying to do and then the code that is failing you on doing that.

Comment: Thanks - I tried it and I understand. I also amended it to get the full file path on the output BUT can you use split when it comes to text after the file path as opposed to your example where you are taking what precedes the .txt? Technically my example is just a few characters after the actual file path? Thanks

Comment: @Shabbaranks I amended my answer but what you are writing is why you need to go try it and then come back explain what you want better and show what you tried.

Comment: Hi @dcaz as you say its probably my lack of explanation. I have a CSV file which contains a file path (effectively a string) Im referring to this path in my Powershell script but the problem is the path contains text at the end. I am trying to get the file path text up until this point. I do understand the split method but I dont think from my basic understanding this is the way I want to go - is there a method I can use to lookup a string of text up until a point?

Comment: Just to show I am trying (and do have a little Powershell knowledge) 
$NewString1 = Select-String -InputObject $CSVImp.Test2 -Pattern '(foo)'
$NewString1 -replace '(foo)',''
Write-Output $NewString1
But it doesnt work - am I on the right path?

Comment: you need the contents of a file in some path and then you need to remove some stuff at the end? is there one or more lines in the file? if many lines. each line is a path you need to change?

Comment: Last update. ask the question better next time :)

Comment: Hey dcaz managed to get it working. I used a formula in my csv to remove the text I didn't need and then used cav-import. Thanks again